# android studio recyclerview firebase not showing data

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

l am try to build Android book store project using Firebase Database and recyclerview to display my data . But the problem is when i run my app i have empty activity without any error .

RecyclerViewActivity java:

```
package sky.ex.ai.booksstore;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecyclerViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView rviwe;
    ArrayList<BookDetails> plist;
    ItemAdapter itemAdapter;
    FirebaseDatabase fb;
    DatabaseReference ref;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler_view);

        rviwe = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        plist = new ArrayList<BookDetails>();
        fb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        ref = fb.getReference("Library");

        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    BookDetails p = ds.getValue(BookDetails.class);
                    plist.add(new BookDetails(p.bkname,p.bkAuthor));

                    Log.i("THE_CURRENT_USER:::", p.toString());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }


        });
        LinearLayoutManager im = new LinearLayoutManager((this));
        rviwe.setLayoutManager(im);
        itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(plist);
        rviwe.setAdapter(itemAdapter);

    }
}
```

activity_recycler_view xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RecyclerViewActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Item layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="138dp"
        android:layout_height="59dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/book" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/book_name_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Book name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/book_author_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Book Author" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/book_price_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Book price" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Book Details Class

```
package sky.ex.ai.booksstore;

    public class BookDetails {

       String bkAuthor;
       String bkname;

        public BookDetails() {
        }

       public BookDetails(String bkname, String bkAuthor){
           this.bkAuthor = bkAuthor;
           this.bkname = bkname;
       }

        public String getBkAuthor() {
            return bkAuthor;
        }

        public void setBkAuthor(String bkAuthor) {
            this.bkAuthor = bkAuthor;
        }

        public String getBkname() {
            return bkname;
        }

        public void setBkname(String bkname) {
            this.bkname = bkname;
        }
    }
```

Item Adapter java

```
package sky.ex.ai.booksstore
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public ArrayList<BookDetails> itemlist;

    public ItemAdapter(ArrayList<BookDetails> itemlist) {
        this.itemlist = itemlist;
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater
                .from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layot,viewGroup, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(view);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int i) {
        holder.txt_pname.setText("Book Name :" +itemlist.get(i).bkname);
        holder.txt_pid.setText("Book Author :" +itemlist.get(i).bkAuthor);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (itemlist==null)
            return 0;
        else  return itemlist.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public ImageButton imgb1;
        public TextView txt_pid,txt_pname,txt_pric;


        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            txt_pid = itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_name_list);
            txt_pname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_author_list);
        }
    }


}
```

Database structure

[image]

any idea please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are calling an asynchronous method. The adapter is being set with empty plist. You need to set items inside the callback method onDataChange, then call notifyDatasetChanged on the adapter to notify it availability of new data. Might need to fix some compiler complaints but this should get you close.

```
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    BookDetails p = ds.getValue(BookDetails.class);
                    plist.add(new BookDetails(p.bkname,p.bkAuthor));
                    Log.i("THE_CURRENT_USER:::", p.toString());
                }
                LinearLayoutManager im = new LinearLayoutManager((RecyclerViewActivity.this));
                rviwe.setLayoutManager(im);
                itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(plist);
                rviwe.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for Answering . can you edit my code above according to your answer please . l am beginner .

Answer (score 2):

After getting data, call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter

```
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                BookDetails p = ds.getValue(BookDetails.class);
                plist.add(new BookDetails(p.bkname,p.bkAuthor));

                Log.i("THE_CURRENT_USER:::", p.toString());
            }
        itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();   
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
```